# Set null to Dagger Singleton object

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, dagger

If in `class1` I set an object that Injected with Dagger and is `@Singleton` to null. And in `class2` I Inject that object again.

Is the object null or it will provide from module again?

Comment: reassingning an injected value won't have any effect on future injection of that. So yes, `class2` will get the same result no matter what you do to the instance in `class1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scoped dependencies (`@Singleton` in this case) are only generated once per Component instance and then re-used for any future injections.
So **if you are using the same instance of your Component** in `class1` and `class2`, they'll get the same object, regardless of whether or not you nullify references to that object.

Comment: No, you will get the same instance that was originally injected in `class1`, regardless of when/if you ever nullify the reference in `class1`